# imagecreatetruecolor(): Invalid image dimensions

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to resize images with PHP but an issue occours:

> ...imagecreatetruecolor(): Invalid image dimensions...

It seems like the image doesn't have the width and the height

```
$upload_dir= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$file= $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 
$filename= $_FILES['file']['name'];

$obj->image= $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']
list($width, $height) = $file;
$width= (int)$width;
$height= (int)$height;
$newimage= imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
```

```html
<form method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="phpfile.php">
<input name="file" type="file" id="file">
<td><input type="submit" value="send"></td>

</form>
```

Help me, please. What is wrong with it ? I tried to print the `$width` and the `$height` but on the screen are printed `0` and `0`.

Comment: `list($width, $height) = $file;` - what do you expect this to do? Because it certainly isn't going to do what you think.

Comment: It is used to have information about the image.Right ?

Comment: No. You're trying to use `list` on the temporary file name given to the uploaded file. You aren't operating on the file itself, just the *name* of the file. Perhaps you want [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)?

Comment: I want to resize the image e create a new image with $width/2 and $height/2 and save it on the server. But if in imagecreatetruecolor ( ) we put numbers instead of variables, how do i get the height and the width of the image ?